# typo3 extbase: how to define additional values in CommandController

Tags: php, extbase

I created a new `CommandController` in one of my extensions and what I need to do now is add an additional field where the backend user can insert some data that can be used inside the `CommandController`.

I tried to google this and what I found was something about `additionalFields` and `fieldProdiver` but I find nothing that's related to the extbase `CommandController` functionality.

I'd be very grateful for any hints on how to achieve this.

Comment: maybe this helps (its german sorry): http://www.codesnip.de/snippets/beispiel-fuer-einen-commandcontroller.html

Answer (score 0):

Mean by "additionalFields" If I get your question, then you need more fields to get more information from backend admin.

In extBase:

**step 1:** add field into extension sql file
Add fields in ext_tables.sql file, located in

> YOUR_EXTENSION/ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE tx_YOUREXTENSION_domain_model_TABLENAME (
   /**your existing fields... **/
   newfield varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, // add new
);
```

**step 2:** Compare database and update in Install tool
Go to backend > install tool > "Compare current database with specification"
and update it.

**step 3:** TCA

> YOUR_EXTENSION/Configuration/TCA/Command.php

add your field name in array of

```
1. "showRecordFieldList" => "newfield"
2. "showitem" => "newfield"
```

Now you have to config your field:

```
'newfield' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'YOUR_LABLE',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 30,
        'eval' => 'trim'
    ),
),
```

For more field config, see [TCA Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/)

**step 4:** Model [get set method]

> YOUR_EXTENSION/Classes/Domain/Model/Command.php

```
/**
 * newfield
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $newfield = '';

/**
 * Returns the newfield
 *
 * @return string $newfield
 */
public function getNewfield() {
    return $this->newfield;
}

/**
 * Sets the newfield
 *
 * @param string $newfield
 * @return void
 */
public function setNewfield($newfield) {
    $this->newfield= $newfield;
}
```

**step 5:** Clear cache
Last and most important ;) clear install tool cache